# Groovy grapes grab from ivy configuration pom is not generated and seeing the parse exception

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, groovy

When groovy run from jenkins pipieline we are getting below exception and observed that pom is not downloaded to groovy directory, both ivy-FLOCAL-SNAPSHOT.xml.original & ivy-LOCAL-SNAPSHOT.xml are ivy-module config.

ivy-FLOCAL-SNAPSHOT.xml.original - should be pom.xml, we are seeing the nexus pom.xml in the nexus
ivy-FLOCAL-SNAPSHOT.xml - this should be ivy-module config, this is generated correctly
Not sure what might be the reason. Any help here appreciated.

Groovy file which has the below grapes

```
@Grapes([@Grab(group='com.company.java.framework',module='t-interfaces',version='T-SNAPSHOT'),@Grab(group='com.company.java.framework', module='t-common', version='T-SNAPSHOT')])
```

grapeConfig.xml

```
<ivysettings>
        <settings defaultResolver="downloadGrapes" />
        <property name="ivy.cache.ttl.default" value="2h" />
        <property name="nexus-public" value="http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-central/" />
        <property name="nexus-central" value="http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-central2/" />
        <property name="nexus-releases" value="http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/" />
        <property name="nexus-snapshots" value="http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/" />
        <property name="jenkins" value="http://localhost:8081/repository/jenkins/" />   
        <resolvers>
            <chain name="downloadGrapes"  returnFirst="true" >
                <ibiblio name="maven" m2compatible="true" root="${nexus-releases}" />
                <ibiblio name="maven-snapshots" m2compatible="true" root="${nexus-snapshots}" />
                <ibiblio name="nexus" m2compatible="true" root="${nexus-public}" />
                <ibiblio name="nexus" m2compatible="true" root="${nexus-central}" />
                <ibiblio name="jenkins" m2compatible="true" root="${jenkins}" />
                <filesystem name="cachedGrapes">
                    <ivy pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml" />
                    <artifact pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
                </filesystem>
            </chain>
        </resolvers>
    </ivysettings>
```

/apps/dev/jenkins/.groovy/grapes/com.company.java.framework/t-common/ivydata-LOCAL-SNAPSHOT.properties

```
#ivy cached data file for com.company.java.framework#t-common;LOCAL-SNAPSHOT
#Thu Mar 14 10:03:15 GMT 2024
artifact\:ivy\#ivy.original\#xml\#1296785679.original=artifact\:ivy\#ivy.original\#xml\#1296785679
resolver=maven-snapshots
artifact\:ivy\#ivy\#xml\#-137639680.original=artifact\:t-common\#pom.original\#pom\#1893525653
artifact\:t-common\#jar\#jar\#240962991.location=http\://localhost.ad.msdsprd.com\:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/com/company/java/framework/t-common/LOCAL-SNAPSHOT/t-common-LOCAL-20240314.093724-2.jar
artifact.resolver=maven-snapshots
artifact\:ivy\#ivy.original\#xml\#1296785679.is-local=true
artifact\:ivy\#ivy.original\#xml\#1296785679.exists=true
artifact\:ivy\#ivy\#xml\#-137639680.exists=true
artifact\:t-common\#pom.original\#pom\#1893525653.exists=true
artifact\:t-common\#jar\#jar\#240962991.is-local=false
artifact\:ivy\#ivy\#xml\#-137639680.location=http\://localhost.ad.msdsprd.com\:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/com/company/java/framework/t-common/LOCAL-SNAPSHOT/t-common-LOCAL-20240314.093724-2.pom
artifact\:t-common\#jar\#jar\#240962991.original=artifact\:t-common\#jar\#jar\#240962991
artifact\:ivy\#ivy.original\#xml\#1296785679.location=/var/lib/jenkins/.groovy/grapes/com.company.java.framework/t-common/ivy-LOCAL-SNAPSHOT.xml
artifact\:t-common\#pom.original\#pom\#1893525653.location=http\://localhost.ad.msdsprd.com\:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/com/company/java/framework/t-common/LOCAL-SNAPSHOT/t-common-LOCAL-20240314.093724-2.pom
artifact\:t-common\#jar\#jar\#240962991.exists=true
artifact\:ivy\#ivy\#xml\#-137639680.is-local=false
artifact\:t-common\#pom.original\#pom\#1893525653.is-local=false
artifact\:t-common\#pom.original\#pom\#1893525653.original=artifact\:t-common\#pom.original\#pom\#1893525653
```

/apps/dev/jenkins/.groovy/grapes/com.company.java.framework/t-common/ivy-LOCAL-SNAPSHOT.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
            <info organisation="com.company.java.framework"> 
</info>
    </ivy-module>
```

/apps/dev/jenkins/.groovy/grapes/com.company.java.framework/t-common/ivy-FLOCAL-SNAPSHOT.xml.original

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
            <info organisation="com.company.java.framework"> 
</info>
    </ivy-module>
```